# Not able to run Test Automation using Xamarin.UITest from Visual Studio on my local emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-emulator, xamarin-test-cloud

We are doing investigation for the Test Clouds for our Android and IOS apps. I made a test snippet which installs and launches the android app. And then takes the screenshot. I am using Visual Studio to write the tests. And Visual Studio emulator to run the android app and xamarin test. Xamarin test is able to install the app, but then throws the error. Code and Errors can be found below.

Other observations:

1. I am using Test account for my investigations which is free for 30 days.
2. But I don't see my computer added in the link: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/computers. While, I have logged in from Visual Studio in my PC.
3. Due to this I can't copy the license file too. Can that be the reason? If yes, what is the best way to investigate this without getting full subscription.

Code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
        AndroidApp app;
        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            // TODO: If the Android app being tested is included in the solution then open
            // the Unit Tests window, right click Test Apps, select Add App Project
            // and select the app projects that should be tested.
            app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                // TODO: Update this path to point to your Android app and uncomment the
                // code if the app is not included in the solution.
                .ApkFile(@"C:\MobileOnly\SampleProjects\AndroidSampleProjects\InfraTest\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk")
                // .InstalledApp("com.microsoft.mobile.infratest")
                .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.Clear);

        }

        [Test]
        public void AppLaunches()
        {
            app.Screenshot("First screen.");
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Test Name: AppLaunches
Test FullName: XamarinUITest.Tests.AppLaunches
Test Source: : line 0
Test Outcome: Failed
Test Duration: 0:00:11.233

Result StackTrace:
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Processes.ProcessRunner.Run(String path, String arguments)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Commands.CommandAdbInstallPackage.Execute(IProcessRunner processRunner, IAndroidSdkTools androidSdkTools)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.InstallApps(ApkFile[] apkFiles)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.EnsureInstalled(ApkFile appApkFile, ApkFile testServerApkFile)
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration)
at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
at XamarinUITest.Tests.BeforeEachTest() in C:\MobileOnly\SampleProjects\AndroidSampleProjects\XamarinUITest\XamarinUITest\Tests.cs:line 22
Result Message: 
SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\NugetCache\androidsdk.23.0.4\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.138.177:5555 install "C:\Users\gunjansa\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-6EAAB1A4CD21F05DB755FBC781EAD620D4ADACBC\final-D9BA1DA5963F9B7853DABC6DEC56BFF2F4740ADE.apk" - exit code: -1073740940
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

pkg: /data/local/tmp/final-D9BA1DA5963F9B7853DABC6DEC56BFF2F4740ADE.apk

Answer (score 0):

Update the Xamarin.UITest NuGet and try

```
public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            // TODO: If the Android app being tested is included in the solution then open
            // the Unit Tests window, right click Test Apps, select Add App Project
            // and select the app projects that should be tested.
            app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .StartApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do below actions

1. Restore your UITest project packages
2. Make sure that you dont see any app named with the package id though the app is completely uninstalled from the device. Often this is the case where uitests uninstalls the existing version of the app and leaves the folders behind causing this issue.

Hope this resolves your issue.